# Signal Generator Output Impedance Matching and Floating Ground

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, signal, impedance-matching, function-generator

I am attempting to recreate a signal generator circuit based on the XR2206, as seen in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbkBmhBM0wI&list=LL&index=1&ab_channel=ScullcomHobbyElectronics). The schematic uses op-amps for offset cancellation and output amplitude matching. To avoid the need for a symmetrical power supply, a **floating ground** is formed using a voltage divider.
[image: Schematic from the video]

The part I find confusing is the presence of two parallel 100-ohm resistors in series with the op-amp output of U3A, explained in the video as impedance matching for a 50-ohm standard. However, the floating ground is formed by 1k resistors in series at the other end of the circuit.

1. Is a 1k resistor sufficient to provide the necessary current for achieving a 50-ohm output impedance at frequencies ranging from 1Hz to 1MHz, considering that the signal generator won't share a common ground with the tested circuit?
2. Would it be beneficial to buffer the floating ground with an op-amp of equal or higher bandwidth?
3. Is it reasonable to consider omitting U3B, as it appears to only buffer the output from the op-amp? Similarly, can U5B be omitted, and the square wave output derived directly from the 74HC14 ?

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbkBmhBM0wI&list=LL&index=1&ab_channel=ScullcomHobbyElectronics), [Link to schematic pdf](http://www.scullcom.com/Function_Generator_Schematic.pdf),
[XR2206 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Kits/XR2206_104_020808.pdf)

Comment: There's another error on that diagram too so, I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: Is it the 1K resistor on the input of the inverting buffer, which operates on a 5V compared to a 12V signal, or the capacitor between the amplifier units for the square wave signal?

Comment: The capacitor on pin 5 to U5B will cause pin 5 to float and, that's the error I saw. I stopped looking at it after that.